# Entity Framework return integer instead of table data?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

[image]

```
USE [prjMarlin]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CriticalDateDiary]    Script Date: 19/07/2017 3:55:51 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    GO
    ALTER  PROCEDURE  [dbo].[CriticalDateDiary]

    AS

     SET NOCOUNT  ON

    DECLARE @ColumnsTable TABLE ([ColumnName] VARCHAR(50));

    INSERT INTO @ColumnsTable ([ColumnName])
    SELECT DISTINCT '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(48), WFStepName) + ']'
    FROM   vwTenureWorkFlowStepReport       
    --where WorkFlowId='a5a23e7e-31ea-439e-b823-179a3bd731ec' 


    DECLARE @PivotColumns VARCHAR(MAX), @TotalColumn VARCHAR(MAX), @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @PivotColumns = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [ColumnName])
                                       FROM   @ColumnsTable
                                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''));


    SET @TotalColumn = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ' + ISNULL(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [ColumnName]) + ', 0)'
                                      FROM   @ColumnsTable
                                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3, ''));

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT *, (' + @TotalColumn + ') AS [Total]
    FROM   (SELECT Tenure,GETDATE() AS CurrentTime,[WFStepName],[StepExpectedEndTime]
            FROM   [vwRunningTenureWorkFlowStepReport]) AS t 
           PIVOT (MAX([StepExpectedEndTime])  FOR WFStepName IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS p;';


    exec(@SQL)
```

When i use database first through entity framework, this stored procedure gets detected as a return type of integer instead of table data?  Any suggestion?

Comment: All procedures have a return value of int, called retval, is that it?

Comment: Yes it is returning retval but how do i get the returned data as seen in the image.  Is it possible to create a table from this output?  ie create a table at runtime to hold this data?

Comment: Show your EF code.

Comment: No EF code to show...when i do a update by database, the return type detected is an integer

Answer (score 0):

Found no satisfactory method that wan't messy, hence i created a script to generate a table as the end result.